# SQL query excluding date ranges from a table of period

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, date, range

I have a period and I want to exclude ranges of dates

for exemple

```
id   startDate  endDate
316  2015-02-01     NULL
```

exclusion table

```
id    ExclusionStartDate ExclusionEndDate

316   2015-02-15         2015-02-18     
316   2015-03-10         2015-03-15 
316   2015-04-01         2015-04-30
```

I search for result :

```
Id       startDate            endDate

316   2015-02-01              2015-02-14 
316   2015-02-19              2015-03-09 
316   2015-03-16              2015-03-31 
316   2015-05-01              null
```

can i use recursive query?

Comment: Can you be more clear on the example ?? I think NOT IN (*Exclusion table query*) would do your job

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I would like to split de first priod  into multiple period range by excluding period range in exclusion table  i use sql server 2008

Comment: It sounds like you have no other input than the period ( 2015-02-01 to today ) and the exclusion table and you want a list of date ranges which do not include the date ranges from the exclusion table.  Is that right?

Comment: input period   |----------------------------------------|           
excluded period             |-----|         |-----|
output result     |----------|     
                  |-------|      
                     |-------|

Comment: Also, what database are you using?  Please tag the question with your answer.

Comment: so you want all the rows from [exclusion] where the end date is after your period start date and the startdate is before your period end date?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
DECLARE @i TABLE(id int, sd DATE, ed DATE)
DECLARE @e TABLE(id int, sd DATE, ed DATE)

INSERT INTO @i VALUES
(316, '20150201', NULL),
(317, '20150202', NULL)
INSERT INTO @e VALUES
(316, '20150215', '20150218'),
(316, '20150310', '20150315'),
(316, '20150401', '20150430'),
(317, '20150405', '20150530')


;WITH cte AS
(
    SELECT id, sd, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY id ORDER BY ord, sd) AS rn FROM 
    (
      SELECT id, sd, 0 AS ord FROM @i
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, DATEADD(dd, -1, sd), 1 AS ord FROM @e
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, DATEADD(dd, 1, ed), 1 AS ord FROM @e
      UNION ALL
      SELECT id, ed, 2 AS ord FROM @i
    ) t
)

SELECT c1.id, c1.sd, c2.sd AS ed FROM cte c1
JOIN cte c2 ON c1.rn + 1 = c2.rn AND c1.id = c2.id
WHERE c2.rn % 2 = 0
ORDER BY c2.id, c2.rn
```

Output:

```
id  sd          ed
316 2015-02-01  2015-02-14
316 2015-02-19  2015-03-09
316 2015-03-16  2015-03-31
316 2015-05-01  NULL
317 2015-02-02  2015-04-04
317 2015-05-31  NULL
```

Comment: Very clever approach.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need recursive queries.  You can just list all the dates, and whether they are start or end dates and then reconstruct the periods.  If you assume that the exclusion periods do not overlap (as in your example)

```
select t.*
from (select id, dte as startDate,
             lead(dte) over (partition by id order by dte) as endDate,
             isStart
      from ((select id, startDate as dte, 1 as isStart from example) union all
            (select id, endDate as dte, 0 as isStart from example) union all
            (select id, exclustionstartDate - interval 1 day as dte, 1 as isStart from exclusion) union all
            (select id, exclustionendDate + interval 1 day as dte, 0 as IsStart from exclusion)
           ) t
     ) t
where isStart = 1;
```

The syntax for adding a day to a date depends on the database.  This just uses `+ interval 1 day`, but use the appropriate logic for your database.